# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when update list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get category-list from server. And also I have button `Edit` near each category. This open modal with `input` and `submit button`. When I click button my category edit and my list must be updated.

But instead `update` list I have error in Table.js:

## Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

### it happen because:

that `data.data` is undefined  in ChangeCategory.js after this line:
 `const data = await response.json();`

## But how to fix it?

In component home my data come normally.

### Maybe it related with method `PUT` in `ChangeCategory.js`?

`/.....` - Code which I delete in question just to have less code in the question.
Also I comment line which iplement update list

### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    numberId: "",              
    isOpened: false
  });

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(/......) {
        const response = await fetch(`/.....`, {/.......}); 
        const data = await response.json();
             setValue(prev => ({ ...prev,  listCategory: data.data,  /......   }));
    }  fetchData( /..... ); 
  }, [ /..... ]);

const changeId = (argNumberId) => {         
     setValue({
        ...value,
        numberId: argNumberId,
        isOpened: true
    });};
    
const updateList = data => {      //  METHOD WHICH UPDATE LIST
    setValue({
        ...value,
        listCategory: data
    })
}

  return (
    <div>
     <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory}  changeId={changeId}  valueId={value.numberId} />
    
     {value.isOpened && <ChangeCategory value={value.numberId} updateList={updateList}/>} 
   </div>);};
```

### ChangeCategory.js:

```
const ChangeCategory = (props) => {
    const { /....... } = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          title: '',
      },
    onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/${props.value}`, {
           method: PUT,    /.......} ) 
        const data = await response.json();  

        props.updateList(data.data);    // CALL FUNCTION updateList

       }});
    
   return (    
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       <InputCategory
           /........
       }}/>
          <button type="submit">Edit</button>
     </form>
   </div>);};
```

### Table.js:

```
export default (props) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>  
        <th>TITLE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id} </td>
          <td>{item.title} </td>
          <td><button onClick={() => props.changeId(item.id)}>Edit</button></td> 
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

response from server:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"title":"animals"}, {"id":2,"title":"space"}, {"id":3,"title":"sport"}]}
```

Comment: Without reading your question: the error says you're calling `.map` on a variable or object property that doesn't exist, so verify that it actually exists before calling functions it. E.g `if (thing) { derived = thing.map(...); } else { ... }`

Comment: What is the value of `data` on your `ChangeCategory.js`'s `onSubmit` method? It seems that `data.data` is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for your code?

Comment: Check in your useEffect that if `listCategory: data.data` has correct value, that is if `data.data` is an array?

Comment: @mgarcia Yes I checked it realy undefined after this line:
`const data = await response.json();`
but how to fix it?

Comment: @mgarcia In component `Home.js` my data come normally. Maybe it related with method `PUT` in `ChangeCategory.js`?

Comment: @Jagrati In component Home.js my data come normally. But if I in ChangeCategory.js  `console.log(data.data)`
after this line: `const data = await response.json();` I see: undefined. Maybe it related with method `PUT` in ChangeCategory.js?

Comment: TMH;DR. Giant text doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map` function runs even before you recieve your data, it can't do so on an `undefined` or `null` objects.

You can either:

- Have a default prop value that your `.map` function will run on some default object.
- Conditionally check for said prop object value. `{props.dataAttribute ? props.dataAttribute.map(...) : null}`

I would recomend doing both.